# C# WPF How to set MainWindow.contentControl.Content from already opened UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

How do I set the MainWindow.contentControl.Content from an already opened UserControl?

In my MainWindow I load an UserControl from where I want to override the MainWindow.contentControl.Content again but when I do so my whole menu disappears which is defined above the ContentControl :(

**[CODE] MainWindow**

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.contentControl.Content = new MyUserControl();
    }
```

***[XAML] MainWindow***

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_Application">
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

**[CODE] MyUserControl**

```
public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new MyUserControlNEW();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign Application.Current.MainWindow.Content you actually remove the root Grid of your window.

One solution is to find the ContentControl by name like this:

```
(Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("contentControl") as ContentControl).Content = new MyUserControlNEW();
```

But you really should avoid manipulating controls in this way for the sake of maintainability of your code. Try to implement MVVM pattern.

Comment: This is exactly what I have searched for. Thank you so much!!! As soon as possible I'll try to understand the MVVM pattern.